# Why I need to explicitly add the fragment and activity dependencies in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

I don't understand, while learning through a codelab in android they want me to add the following dependencies to the android build.gradle

```
implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.4.0"
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.4.1"
```

But I am not able to figure out what difference does it create?

Link to the code lab: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-app-permissions#6

Comment: You didn't link to the specific codelab, so we can only guess. Have you tried _not_ adding those dependencies and see what fails later on in the codelab?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Oh my god is this you? I am a big fan of yours, the work you do in open source for android is truly inspirational. Yes, I tried to remove these dependencies and it makes no difference.

Comment: Hey @ianhanniballake, I am too stuck in the same. I have older projects that doesn't explicitly call out these dependencies, but still work with fragment. Cannot understand from the google docs if there is any change.

Comment: Got my answer after reading the following blog-
https://vtsen.hashnode.dev/recommended-ways-to-create-viewmodel-or-androidviewmodel
If we need to use functionalities like by viewModels() etc, we need this dependency. otherwise not.